# How to repeat the values of an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have initialised an NSArray to store my imagefile names. The array contains the name of image files, which I'm using in my tableview. Now, my array contains only 5 images. But my tableview has many number of cells (greater than 5). I need to use my array to display images in my tableview in such a way that, when the 5th image is displayed on the 5th cell, again the first image must be shown on the 6th cell, 2nd image on 7th cell..and this loop must go on for ever.

To be more specific. It must be like.

```
image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,image1....& on..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
NSUInterger index = indexPath.row % 5;
NSString *imageName = imageArray[index];
```